# How do I update two UITableViewControllers from UIPickerView case statement

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview, urlsession

So I have two UITableViews in one ViewController, that are meant to be updated depending on the user's UIPickerView selection. I have two functions which call an API, and display the results in the tables.I want the table views to be updated, but currently, they new data is added to bottom of the table. My question is how do I update the table? I've tried calling reloadTable() on them, but nothing.

This is the function that calls the API, and displays the data

```
func fetchDataW() {
        
        print("This is the Sprints rank function\n")
        
        let url = URL(string: Constants.rankingAPI)
        guard let requestUrl = url else {
            fatalError()
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        
        group.enter()
        
        request.httpBody = u20VC.paramW.description.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in
                
                // Check for Error
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error took place \(error)")
                    return
                }
                // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
                if let data = data, var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    
                    do{
                        dataString = "<table>" + dataString

                        let docu = HTMLDocument(string: dataString)
                       
                        let elements = docu.querySelectorAll("td")
                        
                        let first5 = Array(elements.prefix(55))
                        
                        let first = Rankings(rank: first5[0].textContent,
                                             mark: first5[1].textContent,
                                             wind: first5[3].textContent,
                                             name: first5[4].textContent,
                                             club: first5[6].textContent,
                                             yob: first5[7].textContent,
                                             plc: first5[8].textContent,
                                             location: first5[9].textContent,
                                             date: first5[10].textContent)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            tblWomen.dataSource = self
                            tblWomen.delegate = self
                            tblWomen.reloadData()
                        }
                        
                        listW.append(first)
                        listW.append(second)
                        listW.append(third)
                        listW.append(fourth)
                        listW.append(fifth)

                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            group.leave()
    }
```

And here is my case statement for the PickerView.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch row {
            case 0:
                u20VC.paramM = Parameters.u20_100mParamsM
                u20VC.paramW = Parameters.u20_100mParamsM
                self.tblMen.reloadData()
                self.tblWomen.reloadData()
                self.fetchDataM()
                self.fetchDataW()
        default:
             ...
}
```

Each time a PickerView item is selected, the value of u20VC.paramM and u20VC.paramW are changed to the correct HTTPBody parameters, and the functions that make the API call(fetchDataM() and fetchDataW() ) are called.

The DataSource is in the function running on the main thread.

Where do I call the reloadData() function?

Comment: can you please show your delegate and data source? and did you check your Apis Returning Data Properly

Comment: Where are you table views?  What's the relationship between the table views and the picker view selection(s)?